# javax.xml attributes of TransformerFactory.setAttribute

Tags: java, xml

Where can I find a list of attributes that are legal inputs for javax.xml.TranformerFactory.setAttribute(String,String)? Inputting an illegal string yields a nasty runtime exception.

Answer (score 0):

The attributes you can use are specific to a particular XSLT implementation. The attributes you can use for Saxon, for example, are listed here:

http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/configuration/config-features.xml

while those for XSLTC are here:

http://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/xsltc_usage.html#api-attributes